# Correctly posting JSON data to restful webservice netbeans

Tags: java, json, web-services, netbeans

I have created a restful webservice using the "generate web services from database option" in netbeans.
I have deployed this in wildfly and noticed that while GET requests work, POST requests do not.
Here is the part of my java code which accepts the POST connections:

```
@POST
    @Override
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void create(XtgpsActivity entity) {
        super.create(entity);


    }
```

The create method takes a parameter of type XtgpsActivity. This is the XtgpsActivity class:

```
//packages and imports list removed
@Entity
@Table(name = "xtgps_Activity")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "XtgpsActivity.findAll", query = "SELECT x FROM XtgpsActivity x"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "XtgpsActivity.findById", query = "SELECT x FROM XtgpsActivity x WHERE x.id = :id")})
public class XtgpsActivity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Integer id;
    @JoinColumn(name = "BaseItemId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    @ManyToOne
    private XtgpsBaseItem baseItemId;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "activityId")
    private Collection<XtgpsNearByActivity> xtgpsNearByActivityCollection;

    public XtgpsActivity() {
    }

    public XtgpsActivity(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public XtgpsBaseItem getBaseItemId() {
        return baseItemId;
    }

    public void setBaseItemId(XtgpsBaseItem baseItemId) {
        this.baseItemId = baseItemId;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<XtgpsNearByActivity> getXtgpsNearByActivityCollection() {
        return xtgpsNearByActivityCollection;
    }

    public void setXtgpsNearByActivityCollection(Collection<XtgpsNearByActivity> xtgpsNearByActivityCollection) {
        this.xtgpsNearByActivityCollection = xtgpsNearByActivityCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof XtgpsActivity)) {
            return false;
        }
        XtgpsActivity other = (XtgpsActivity) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "au.com.xitech.XtgpsActivity[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

This is the create method in the superclass:

```
public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }
```

Since the related table only has two columns id and baseitemid, and id is a primary key, I am sending my POST JSON data as this:

```
{"baseitemid":"2"}
```

However, when i post data in this format, I get an error:

```
http://localhost:8089/xxx/api/activity/ 400 (Bad Request)
```

I believe this is because of an issue with the JSON data I send. What is the correct way to create a JSON array for the post request?

**PS**: I have also attached my ajax call below. Note I did this after enabling CORS in the browser.

```
$('#submit_it').click(function(e) {
        //console.log("submit button has been clicked");
        e.preventDefault(); //cancel form submit

        var jsObj = $post_example.serializeObject()
            , ajaxObj = {};

        //console.log(jsObj);
        alert(JSON.stringify(jsObj));
        ajaxObj = {  
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8089/xxx/api/activity/", 
            data: JSON.stringify(jsObj),
            contentType:"application/json",
            success: function(data) { 
                //console.log(data);
                if(data[0].HTTP_CODE == 200) {
                    $('#div_ajaxResponse').text( data[0].MSG );
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Error " + jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders() + " " + errorThrown);
            },

            complete: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                //console.log( XMLHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders() );
            }, 
            dataType: "json" //request JSON
        };

        $.ajax(ajaxObj);
    });
```

Comment: Since the question doesn't seem to involve PHP, you should remove that tag.

Comment: Btw.. have you tried to just do: `data: jsObj,` instead of `data: JSON.stringify(jsObj),`?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson tried this, didnt work. I removed the tag too. I have a feeling the JSON data is not correctly sent, so it fails to convert to a entity object, as required by the create method. Is there any standard of specifying the json data in this regard?

Comment: Start by checking what your browser actually is sending. You can usually see the real request under the network tab in the browsers developer tools. Making sure that it sends proper JSON. When/if it does, try some tool like postman to send some JSON data to your Java API and see if it handles it correctly.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks a lot for postman, that was an epic find. Still trying to fix it, will update progress.

Answer (score 0):

The value passed in json is parsed as a numeric value, so sending as (without quotes for the value)

```
{
  "baseitemid":2
  }
```

worked.